# Convert Double to Datetime including milliseconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime, type-conversion

I am writing a parser and have come to an issue that i've been unable to tackle. I have a number (double) 734139.045000000040 present in a text file which is the date. I need to convert this number into a DateTime format (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff).

I have the following code which gives me a date far into the future and is definately wrong and am wondering what i need to do in order to get the correct date. Unfortunately i do not have the dateTime value it should be, all i know is this file had been generated sometime late 2010 or 2011.

I would appreciate any help or guidance on this.

```
double d = double.Parse(line);
DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);

MessageBox.Show(conv.ToString());
```

The resulting messagebox shows the conversion as being 01/01/3910 01:04:48
Please help! and thank you

Comment: What is that number meant to represent? It's just a number at the moment - is it meant to be the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch? Number of seconds? Something entirely different? Also note that `DateTime` itself doesn't have a format - it's just the value.

Comment: What date `734139.045000000040` represents?

Comment: @Jon Skeet & Microsft DN - The number represents a date of which i dont know, i only know that it should be somewhere in late 2010 or 2011. Are there different methods i can do by trial and error.

Comment: Well where did this data come from? Can't you ask that data source what it's meant to be? You could very easily end up with something *subtly* wrong if you're not careful. It's never a good idea to interpret data in a particular way with no clue as to what it's really meant to represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is "**a matlab serial date number**" like you mentioned in one of your comments, use the following to parse it:

```
DateTime conv = new DateTime(1, 1, 1).AddDays(734139.045000000040).AddYears(-1)
```

Results: 1/3/2010 1:04:48 AM.

This adds the value as days to the date 0001/01/01 and then subtract one year. The reason is .Net dates start from 0001/01/01, while Matlab starts from 0000/00/00.

Answer (score 4):

Quick calculation shows that 734,139 days works out to approximately 2,011 years and 4 months. That's without taking leap years into account. I would suspect, then, that 1.0 means one day. So, let's see:

```
var days = 734139.045000000040;
var theDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1).AddDays(days);
Console.WriteLine(theDate);
```

Output is:

```
2011/01/03 01:04:48
```

Seems to work.

I figured this out by trial and error. The initial assumption is that the number is an offset from some base value, usually called the epoch date. Typically the offset is a number of milliseconds, seconds, or days. I figured it more likely that the offset value was expressed in days, for two reasons:

1. The offset is pretty small. If it were seconds, it would be 8.5 days, and if it were milliseconds it would be about 12 hours.
2. It would be unusual to have a `double` to express the number of milliseconds, and almost as unusual to have it express a number of seconds. Typically you'd express seconds or milliseconds as a `long`. This isn't universally true, but most common in my experience.

So, figuring that it was days, I divided by 365 to get a quick estimate and found that it's about 2,011 years. That matched with your comment that the date is supposed to be in "late 2010 or 2011".

### Update

If you want to get the number of milliseconds, you can treat it as a `TimeSpan`:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(days);
var millis = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, its the closest it seems to work at the moment, i have asked for more information form the source and then could verify, would it be possible to identify the millseconds?

Comment: I've just got some more information, the number is represneted as a matlab serial date number http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/represent-date-and-times-in-MATLAB.html now i just need to incorporate this into C#

Comment: @Rg786 The page you linked in your comment mentions that the **matlab serial date number** starts from 0000/00/00. The accepted answer starts from 0001/01/01, so if you use it you'll end up with an extra year (2011 instead of 2010). As I mentioned in my answer below, you need to subtract a year from the result to get the correct date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong approach here. According to the docs regarding [FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx):

> The d parameter is a double-precision floating-point number that represents a date as the number of days before or after the base date, midnight, 30 December 1899. The sign and integral part of d encode the date as a positive or negative day displacement from 30 December 1899, and the absolute value of the fractional part of d encodes the time of day as a fraction of a day displacement from midnight. d must be a value between negative 657435.0 through positive 2958465.99999999.

It is far more likely that the number is actually in milliseconds. If that suits your needs, then you can use the [following DateTime constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx):

> DateTime conv = new DateTime((long)d);

Here d means

> A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

You need to test and tell us if that suits your needs (or how it does not) to give you further useful infromation.

Comment: Well, `new DateTime();` takes a `long` parameter, and the value "734139.045000000040" that the OP is trying to parse is definitely not integral. Do you see the fraction point right there?